# Python: Passing Function Arguments for strings

Tags: python

I am practicing with "Think Python", Exercise 8.1 that:

"Write a function that takes a string as an argument and displays the letters backward, one per line."

I am able to do this question, by using banana as an example to print each letter per line.

```
index = 0
fruit = "banana"
while index < len(fruit):
    letter = fruit[len(fruit)-index-1]
    print letter
    index = index + 1
```

However, I would like to generalize the situation to any input words and I got the problem, my code is

```
index = 0
def apple(fruit):
    while index < len(fruit):
        letter = fruit[len(fruit)-index-1]
        print letter
        index = index + 1

apple('banana')
```

The corresponding errors are:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exercise8.1_mod.py", line 21, in <module>
    apple('banana')
  File "exercise8.1_mod.py", line 16, in apple
    while index < len(fruit):
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'index' referenced before assignment
```

I think there should be problems concerned with the function arguments used. Any helps will be appreciated.

Comment: Just put your `index = 0` inside your function as well (at the beginning of it).

Comment: @BrenBarn if you explain him y he need to keep inside so that he will learn about local and global variables right? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your program got error due to your accessing a global variable in your method and trying to change its value

```
index = 0
def apple(fruit):
    .....
    index = index + 1
    ....    
apple('banana')
```

this give you error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'index' referenced before assignment`

but if you give

```
def apple(fruit):
        global index
        .....
        index = index + 1
        ....
```

this produces correct result

in python we have `Global variable` and `Local variables`

please go throught [this](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value)

> *In Python, variables that are only referenced inside a function are implicitly global. If a variable is assigned a new value anywhere
>   within the function’s body, it’s assumed to be a local. If a variable
>   is ever assigned a new value inside the function, the variable is
>   implicitly local, and you need to explicitly declare it as global.*

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation on local and global variables. It does help a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This should probably work better:

```
def apple(fruit):
    for letter in fruit[::-1]:
        print letter

apple('banana')
```

This works by indexing the string in reverse, a built in python function known as slicing.

[Reverse a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931092/reverse-a-string-in-python)

Comment: thx beiller, I learn from your statement,  fruit[::-1], it is neat and  sound pretty for me~!

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a value to `index` before you use it.

```
def apple(fruit):
    index = 0  # assign value to index
    while index < len(fruit):
        letter = fruit[len(fruit)-index-1]
        print letter
        index = index + 1
apple("peach")
h
c
a
e
p
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment on *assign value to index*. My program gets run. Thx =]